# How to mock/create a Firebase Usercredentials object for tests

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-test

how do I create a UserCredential Object when testing?

I am trying to test my authRepository like this :

```dart
      test('', () async {
        when(
          () => mockFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: 'test@test.de', password: '123456'),
        ).thenAnswer((realInvocation) => ) // I need to return a Future<UserCredential> here);
    
        final result = await authRepository.signUpWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: 'test@test.de', password: '123456');
    
      });
```

but in order to stub `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` I need to return a
`Future<UserCredential>`

How do I create such an object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found a working solution. Turns out I had to mock it just like any other object:

```dart
class MockUserCredential extends Mock implements UserCredential {}
```

To modify this mock object, stubbing the needed property works as expected :

```dart
mockCredential = MockUserCredential();
when(() => mockCredential.user).thenReturn(_mockUser);
```

Comment: Hi how did you define _mockUser? Will you be able to post a code example?

Comment: Same as the credentials : 
`class MockUser extends Mock implements User {}
final MockUser _mockUser = MockUser();`